# Find a regular expression for the regular language L={w | w is decimal notation for an integer that is a multiple of 4}

Tags: expression

Can anyone figure out how to do this problem? Need some help..

Comment: please explain a little with your answer

Answer (score 0):

`0|4|8|(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)*((0|2|4|8)(0|4|8)|(1|3|5|7)(2|6))`

Comment: Can you explain your answer?